# Access VBA to Excel, add apostrophe

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have been trying to figure this out for over a week now.  I need to have Excel, via Access add an apostrophe to the 2nd column in an Excel file.  I first tested the vba in Excel separate from Access and it worked.  However, when I attempt to do the via Access with the appropriate (or so I think) object references, I get "an overflow" message via Access after I click on the command button.

> The error is Runtime error 6 "Overflow"

it points to this line:

```
For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, mc).End(xlUp).Row
```

---

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim objWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
    objExcel.Visible = True

    Set objWB = Workbooks.Open("R:\GMI\Drop\AP04 2018.xlsx", , False)
    Set objWS = objWB.ActiveSheet

    With objWS
        .Range("a2:a7").EntireRow.Insert

        mc = 2 'column I
        For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, mc).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(i, mc).Value = "'" & .Cells(i, mc)
        Next i
    End With

    objWB.SaveAs "C:\EMI\Drop\JV.xlsx"
    objWB.Close
    Set objWB = Nothing
    objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Transactions", "R:GEMI\Drop\TransToday.xlsx", True

    MsgBox "Pre-import/Import complete", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

Comment: What specifically is the error message? It's on your screen right in front of you, but I can't quite read the words from here, no matter how hard I try. What *overflow*? When you step through the code in the debugger, which line specifically is causing the issue?

Comment: Runtime error 6
Overflow
For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, mc).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: So what about answering the rest of the questions I asked? And please do so by making an [edit] to your question and putting them there, in the question itself, where people can see them.

Comment: It points to this line:
For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, mc).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Thank you for your patience

Comment: The error I get now is Run-time error '438' "Object does not support this property or method

 mc = 2 'column I
            For i = 1 To .Cells(mc, Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(mc, i).Value = "'" & .Cells(mc, i).Value
            Next i

Comment: Try changing that to `For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, mc).End(xlUp).Row`   (note the `.`  in front of `Rows` )

Comment: Thank you, I added the . as you suggested (below) and received "Runtime error '6'

mc = 2 'column I
            For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, mc).End(xlUp).Row
                 .Cells(i, mc).Value = "'" & .Cells(i, mc).Value
            Next i

Comment: Do you have fore than 32767 rows?  If so (and you should do this anyway) use `Dim i As Long` rather than Integer

Comment: Yes, more than 32k— just over 200k.  Thank you, that suggestion seems to have help as I ran the command button and it did not error out.  Now it’s extremely slow— any ideas on that please?

Comment: Would it be faster to only add apostrophes to cells in scientific notation?  If so, how can I do that?

Comment: @JessicaHolder Since the answer to your Q was `Integer Overflow, Use Long` the is a duplicate.  Regarding your speed issue, thats a different Q.  The usual answer involves copying the data to a variant array, looping that do apply your changes, and copying the array back to the sheet.  Search "[Excel-vba] Variant Array" on SO, lots of examples there